# oledb retrieve entire record and return from .accdb

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

example of a return function that returns only string value, how do I return multiple values consisting of different data types in a single record by simply calling one function?

```
    public static string selectPassword(string user)
    {
        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
            command.CommandText = "SELECT [Password] FROM [Password_Table] WHERE Password_ID = [@user]";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            connection.Open();

            var value = command.ExecuteScalar();

            return value == DBNull.Value ? null : value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

my record would be searched by Participant_Name, and would need to return Participant_Name, Participant_ID, Address, Contact_Number & Gender fields, all consisting of string, integers etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a data-type which consists of fields and properties that are able to hold the information that you want to retrieve.

Populate an instance of that type in your method, and return it.

Something like this, for instance:

```
public class Participant
{
   public int Id { get; private set; }
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Address {get; set; }


   public Participant( int id, string name, string address )
   {
       this.Id = id;
       this.Name = name;
       this.Address = address;
   }
}

public Participant GetParticipant( string name )
{
    using( var conn = new OleDbConnection (connectionString) )
    {
        using( var cmd = connection.CreateCommand() )
        {
              command.CommandText = "SELECT [Id], [Name], [Address] FROM Participant WHERE [name] LIKE @p_name";


               command.Parameters.Add ("@p_name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = name + "%";

               using( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() )
               {
                    if( !reader.HasRows() ) return null;

                    reader.Read();

                    return new Participant (reader.GetString("Id"), reader.GetString("name"), reader.GetString("address"));
               }
        }
    }

}
```

Note: there can be syntax errors, since I haven't pulled it through the compiler, but I think you'll catch the drift.

Comment: this is brilliant, if he has an entity defined is the best solution. Or he can also return the DataRow or its itemArray directly. but +1 for you as I wrote my answer having thin in mind as well. In real world applications, there should always be a business entity for every kind of record anyway.

Comment: I must have missed it! Its a wow-solution didn't know it could be a simple yet elegant solution! I'm not saying that other answers are wrong, but this appeals to me most as to what I currently know! thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

for your needs you should return a `DataRow` object or an object array which you can get by calling `.ItemArray` on a `DataRow`

what you need to change in your method above is to use a `DataAdapter` and call its `Fill` method to fill a DataTable then return the first row of such DataTable, if any row is present.

you could also do this with the DataReader but then you should construct the array or objects container to return by yourself... I think dataRow.ItemArray is faster to code.

Comment: faster to code, but imho not so friendly to use, since a simple datarow is not typed.